# How to use activerecord-sqlserver-adapter with TinyTDS *and* an Integrated Security connection on Windows *without* saving a password in plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, windows, activerecord

I'm trying to use Rails 3.1. with the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.1.1) and tiny_tds (0.4.5) on a Windows machine.  In reading about TinyTDS and it's use of FreeTDS it looks like I can use Integrated Security (aka Windows Integrated security/NTLM) by putting a domain-qualified name as the user name (e.g. DOMAIN\userbob).  *But* the docs still want me to type my domain user's password in the database.yml file.  That's bad practice because it's insecure and doesn't take advantage of single-sign on, which is part of the point for Integrated Security.

Can I connect without saving a password in plain text in a file?  e.g.

```
developement:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    dataserver: localhost
    database: dev_db
    username: DOMAIN\userbob
#    password: no_no_please_dont_make_me_type_it_here
```

But, even if I put a password I get the following error:

```
TinyTds::Error: Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `initialize'
```

I know my server is running and the current user context can connect because this works:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d dev_db -E
```

Any insights?  Is it possible?  If not, it *should* be.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for the SSO-problem - did you solve your problem in meantime? I get the error `TinyTds::Error: Login failed for user 'xxx'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.`. If I add the password, I get a connection.

Comment: With work, I've managed to get a new error message, `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.`   However, this is confusing because the user account and the system are _on the same domain_.

Answer (score 2):

Enable TCP/IP in "SQL Server Network Configuration" in SQL Server Configuration Manager utility.
Then restart SQL Server service.

Regarding security you will need to supply your own credentials otherwise it will use sa account.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it only gets me past the `Adaptive Server is unavailable` error in favor of the `The login is from an untrusted domain`.  See comment above.  Thanks for helping, though.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently SQL Server 2008 is setup by default to ONLY allow Windows Authentication. To change that you have to open the Management Studio, Right click on your server and select Properties. Select Security and click the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" under Server authentication. This will at least allow you to connect directly to the server until TinyTDS makes the needed changes to allow Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code making the connection is trying to make the process impersonate the security context supplied by the credentials instead of passing the default credentials through to SQL server.

This would allow you to specify different credentials to the current security context. I've used this trick to connect to a server requiring SSIS from an untrusted domain.

I don't know TinyTDS/FreeTDS, perhaps null or empty credentials would make it use the default security context. Try:

```
developement:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    dataserver: localhost
    database: dev_db
```

or

```
developement:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    dataserver: localhost
    database: dev_db
    username:
    password:
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Based on experience, empty credentials will attempt to use the 'sa' account, which is not what I want (_not single-sign-on_).  But it does look like using a username with a back-slash (i.e. a domain account) does attempt to use Windows authentication w/o a password.  Too bad it doesn't work on my domain.  Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

*Try to use*

```
developement:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: dblib
    dataserver: localhost\SQLEXPRESS
    database: dev_db
    username: DOMAIN\userbob
```

or else do you set 2 variant **authentification** in your's sql server? then try to connect with sa user...